# ERROR CASSANDRA: 'ascii' codec can't decode bye 0xe1 in position 27: ordinal not in range(128) cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I'm new in Cassandra and I have a trouble inserting some rows in a database getting the error of the title.

I use cassandra 1.0.8 and cqlsh for doing changes in my database.

Next, I explain the given steps before I get the error:

CREATE A COLUMN FAMILY

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    col1 int PRIMARY KEY,
col2 bigint, 
col3 boolean,
col4 timestamp
);
```

INSERT SEVERAL ROWS WITHOUT SPECIFICYING ALL OF COLUMNS OF THE TABLE

```
insert into test (col1, col2, col3) values (1, 100, true);
insert into test (col1, col2, col3) values (2, 200, false);
```

SELECT FOR CHECKING THAT ROWS HAVE BEEN INSERTED CORRECTLY

```
select * from test;
```

The result is the following:

[image: Result of select * from test]

INSERT A ROW SPECIFICYING A VALUE FOR THE col4 (NOT SPECIFIED BEFORE)

```
insert into test (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (3, 100, true, '2011-02-03');
```

SELECT FOR CHECKING THAT ROW HAS BEEN INSERTED CORRECTLY

```
select * from test;
```

In this SELECT is  the error. The result is the following:

[image]

SELECT EACH COLUMN OF THE TABLE SEPARATELY

```
select col1 from test;
select col2 from test;
select col3 from test;
select col4 from test;
```

it works fine and shows the right values:

[image]

Then, my question is: what's the problem in the first SELECT? what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

NOTE:

If I define col4 as Integer rather than a timestamp it works. However, I've tried to insert col4 as the normalized format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm (I've tried with '2011-02-03 01:05' and '2011-02-03 01:05:10') but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra 1.0.8 shipped with CQL2 and that's where your problem is coming from. I managed to recreate this in 1.0.8 but it works fine with 1.2.x so my advice is **upgrade** if you can.

In C* 1.2.10

```
cqlsh> update db.user set date='2011-02-03 01:05' where user='JCTYpjJlM';
cqlsh> SELECT  * from db.user ;    

 user      | date                     | password
-----------+--------------------------+----------
 xvkYQKerQ |                     null |      765
 JCTYpjJlM | 2011-02-03 01:05:00+0200 |      391
```

Answer (score 0):

@mol

Weird, try to insert col4 as Integer (convert to milliseconds first) or use the normalized format : *yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm*

Accodring to the doc **[here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#reference_ds_dsf_555_yj)**, you can omit the time and just input the date but it seems that breaks something in your case

Comment: When I try to insert col4 as Integer it works. However, I've tried to insert col4 as the normalized format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm (I've tried with '2011-02-03 01:05' and '2011-02-03 01:05:10') but it doesn't work. Thanks!!

Comment: Probably a bug from cqlsh or from Cassandra with date decoding. Which version of Cassandra are you using ?